# Redis Cluster and Cluster Location

Tags: redis

I was reading [this](https://developer.redis.com/operate/redis-at-scale/scalability/exercise-1/) and [this](https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/) Redis article explaining how to create a Cluster.
However, in both he always works using just one machine.

Did this leave me a little confused? Does the Redis cluster work on the same machine, or is using the entire cluster on the same machine just an example and can I distribute it across multiple virtual machines?

Comment: You can distribute it across multiple machines. Just remember to use unique IPs.

Comment: Yes, you can make multiple hosts and configure accordingly. Use different host IP instead of localhost in Redis command. For Example "redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 \
127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005 \
--cluster-replicas 1"